# Halt a jenkins pipeline job early

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In our Jenkins Pipeline job we have a couple of stages, and what I would like is if any of the stages fail, then to have the build stop and not continue on to the further stages.

Here's an example of one of the stages:

```groovy
stage('Building') {
    def result = sh returnStatus: true, script: './build.sh'
    if (result != 0) {
        echo '[FAILURE] Failed to build'
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    }
}
```

The script will fail, and the build result will update, but the job continues on to the next stages. How can I abort or halt the job when this happens?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically that is what the `sh` step does. If you do not capture the result in a variable, you can just run:

```groovy
sh "./build"
```

This will exit if the script returns a non-zero exit code.

If you need to do stuff first, and need to capture the result, you can use a shell step to quit the job

```groovy
stage('Building') {
    def result = sh returnStatus: true, script: './build.sh'
    if (result != 0) {
        echo '[FAILURE] Failed to build'
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
        // do more stuff here

        // this will terminate the job if result is non-zero
        // You don't even have to set the result to FAILURE by hand
        sh "exit ${result}"  
    }
}
```

But the following will give you the same, but seems more sane to do

```groovy
stage('Building') {
    try { 
         sh './build.sh'
    } finally {
        echo '[FAILURE] Failed to build'
    }
}
```

It is also possible to call return in your code. However if you are inside a `stage` it will only return out of that stage. So

```groovy
stage('Building') {
   def result = sh returnStatus: true, script: './build.sh'
   if (result != 0) {
      echo '[FAILURE] Failed to build'
      currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
      return
   }
   echo "This will not be displayed"
}
echo "The build will continue executing from here"
```

wont exit the job, but

```groovy
stage('Building') {
   def result = sh returnStatus: true, script: './build.sh'
}
if (result != 0) {
  echo '[FAILURE] Failed to build'
  currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
  return
}
```

will.

Comment: Doesn't ./build just break it because the folder doesn't exist and exit with code 1. Am I correct in thinking this is a workaround and not an inbuilt solution?

Comment: Doing something like your last example (placing code outside a stage) causes compilation errors for my pipeline (along the lines of "expecting stage"). And I'd like it to exit the entire job.

Comment: Hi Nagev, Unfortenately at the time of writing this still worked. It is very likely that now it won't. Unfortunately I haven't been working with Jenkins for the last few years. Can you tell me what version you are using (of jenkins)?. Then I can investigate and see if I can help you out with this.

Answer (score 15):

Since Jenkins v2 this should also work

```groovy
error('Failed to build')
```

The Job will end with:

```groovy
ERROR: Failed to build
Finished: ERROR
```

Comment: this seems the way to go

Answer (score 10):

Another way to achieve this behavior is to throw an Exception. In fact, this is just what Jenkins itself does. That way, you can also set the build status either to `ABORTED` or `FAILURE`. This example aborts the build:

```groovy
stage('Building') {
    currentBuild.rawBuild.result = Result.ABORTED
    throw new hudson.AbortException('Guess what!')
    echo 'Further code will not be executed'
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Building)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Guess what!
Finished: ABORTED
```

Comment: With Jenkins 2.89.3 this is an error: `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new hudson.AbortException java.lang.String`

Comment: Looks like Sandbox mode is enabled and forbids throwing that Exception. Kind of strange, but disabling Sandbox mode should do the trick.

Comment: Alternatively you can permit the usage via Manage Jenkins > In-process Script Approval

Comment: You can use 
`currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED' error("Aborting the job.")`